# Why can't I type anything in my entry box after a messagebox was run?

Tags: python, tkinter, messagebox, tkinter-entry

My entry box won't work, and I don't know why... If I remove the `messagebox` from the script; I can type things in my entry box, but if I put a `messagebox` in the script again, the entry box won't work.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter

root=tkinter.Tk()
tkinter.messagebox.askquestion("Day", "Is this a new day?")
points =0
def subtracted():
     points = int(pointsToSubtract.get())
     currentpoints=20
     currentpoints=currentpoints - points
     pointLabel.config(text=currentpoints+" total points")
pointLabel = tkinter.Label(root,text="20 points" )
pointLabel.grid(row=0,column=0)


pointsToSubtract = tkinter.Entry(root)
pointsToSubtract.grid(row=1,column=0)

subPoint = tkinter.Button(root,text="Subtract points",command=subtracted)
subPoint.grid(row=2,column=0)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't understand why you show `messagebox`. As for me `messagebox` is for blocking code until you answer and close `messagebox`.

Comment: @quamrana Kinda, what I thought of when I saw that was to put the message box script outside the window loop, and it works, but now I get a window that is blank, and which I have to close manually, but that's not a big issue. Thanks!